# Having next items in a list while we run a for loop

Tags: python, file, for-loop, enumerate, file-read

I'm a beginner in python and I'm writing a code which I'm trying to check if I find a specific item I can check some items before and if I can print the current value.
I wrote this code but I can't get the problem:

```
import re

file1 = open('A.txt', 'r')
file2 = open('B.txt', 'w')
line = file1.readlines()
for index, line in enumerate(file1):
     match = re.search(r'R', line)
     if match:
            for a in range(index, index+2):
                 same = re.search(r'T', line.next())
                 if same:
                        file2.writelines(line)


file2.close()
file1.close()
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: As Camilo said, it's unclear what you want. It appears you may be asking to compare previous checks or check items before you iterate over them? We can better help if you clarify what you want, perhaps demonstrate the output you want and tell us what problem you are currently having.

Comment: I'm trying to find a specified character. then if second next line is another specified character, print the one you found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You weren't very clear with your question, but I suspect that you're trying to do something like this:

You want to make sure that `line1` from fine `A.txt` goes into file `B.txt` if it has `R` character in it, and it is followed by a line that has `T` character in it. Here's a solution for that problem.

```py
import re

file1 = open('A.txt', 'r')
file2 = open('B.txt', 'w')
last_line = file1.readline()
while (current_line := file1.readline()):
    match_last = re.search(r'R', last_line)
    match_current = re.search(r'T', current_line)
    
    if match_last and match_current:
        file2.writelines(last_line)
    last_line = current_line

file2.close()
file1.close()
```

Comment: Yes exactly! I want to check if it has R character then for example in second next line if I have T then print this R. Basically, I want to access to any element before or after.

Comment: Actually it worked. But what about if I want to check second next line?

Comment: you can convert file into a list of lines. `lines = open('A.txt', 'r').readlines()`. and then access `lines[i+1]` to get the next line.

Comment: Could you write it please?